Sphere Online Judge (SPOJ) Python input handling broken?
I'm fairly familiar with input handling in Competitive Programming settings, but I can't make it work in Python for this problem (https://www.spoj.com/problems/MINDIST/) (my solution works in C++ so the problem in itself is not broken). What is the standard way to read input in the SPOJ platform?
Here, this is what will be fed to the stdin:

The first line of the input contains a single integer T, the number of
test cases. T blocks follow.
For each test case, the first line contains two space-separated
integer N (1<=N<=100000) and S (0<=S<=100000000). N-1 lines follow,
each contains three integers X (1<=X<=N), Y (1<=Y<=N) and Z
(1<=Z<=1000), denotes that there is an (undirected) edge weighted Z
between node X and Y. The input is correct.

And an example of fed input would be:
2
5 2
1 2 5
2 3 2
2 4 4
2 5 3
8 6
1 3 2
2 3 2
3 4 6
4 5 3
4 6 4
4 7 2
7 8 3

MRE:
This (just the input handling) gets "runtime error, Non-Zero Exit Code" (but works locally and on online compilers such as ideone):
def get_int():
    return int(input())

def get_ints():
    return map(int, input().split())

T = get_int()
for _ in range(T):
    N, S = get_ints()
    for _ in range(N-1):
        X, Y, Z = get_ints()

It seems the get_ints() call is the problem because this:
def get_int():
    return int(input())

def get_ints():
    return map(int, input().split())

T = get_int()
for _ in range(T):
    N, S = 2, 3
    for _ in range(N-1):
        X, Y, Z = 1, 2, 3

gets (as expected) "wrong answer".
I'm at loss as to why this happens.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The input data actually contains blank lines. If I just filter them out by adding this at the top, the verdict changes from "error" to "wrong answer":
def input(input=input):
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line.strip():
            return line

I consider their input invalid and your input handling correct. The blank lines shouldn't be there, or their input description should mention them. The way it's written, they're not ok.
I figured this out by submitting quite a few times with various tests, for example storing the split() results in a temporary variable and doing while len(temp) != 2: pass. That gave me "time limit exceeded", so I knew the number of elements on the line was wrong.

I'll link the SO in the comment section of the problem this might help other people.

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows I was about to congratulate you for finally getting "accepted", but then I realized you used C++ again :-). I've read the problem now and don't yet see a solution. Is it an algorithm a good competitive coder can come up with with some thinking, or is it rather one that most will have to learn and that might have a paper written about it? (No other hints, please.)

I'm still trying to understand how to get it accepted in Python but it seems the big number of empty lines is fatal. It will appear as a combination of fairly common algorithms for experienced competitive programmers, if you don't know them, I'm not sure you can invent them all and connect them all. Those are all findable without prior knowledge but finding them all and connecting them without prior knowledge about them seems really difficult. For reference I teach Algorithms in university but have limited CP experience (1500 codeforces) and it took me 3 hours to find.

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Thanks. My CF rating is over 1800 (from three contests 11 years ago). But sounds like I won't be able to solve this one.

If you want to try an easier problem that will help (although not in a straightforward manner), I recommend this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQGQnyv_9hI

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Ok I solved that problem ~8.5 years ago. Says LeetCode - I have no recollection :-). I'll try.
